# Unable to Export Data Tier in SQL Server When External Views Exists

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-managed-instance

I am planning on using SSMS, why I am unable to run Tasks->Export Data Tier Application on a database which has views pointing to another database tables. This is in Azure SQL MI.

**Error Message**

```
One or more unsupported elements were found in the schema used as part of a data package.
Error SQL71561: Error validating element [dbo].[vw_ext_customer]: 
View: [dbo].[vw_ext_customer] has an unresolved reference to object
[finance].[dbo].[ext_customer]. External references are not supported when 
creating a package from this platform.
```

**External Table View**

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_ext_customer] AS SELECT * FROM finance.dbo.ext_customer
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I am able to generate bacpac using sqlpackage utility instead of SSMS. Trick is not to verify schema model during export. Not sure why SSMS do not have this parameter or am I missing somewhere. Please find my working code below

```
$ sqlpackage /a:export /ssn:some_server /sdn:databasename /su:username /sp:password /tf:database.bacpac /p:VerifyExtraction=False
```

Answer (score 0):

If the connection fails due to Certificate trust, you can try to override using options like below:

```
$ sqlpackage /a:export /ssn:some_server /sdn:databasename /su:username /sp:password /tf:database.bacpac /p:VerifyExtraction=False /SourceEncryptConnection:False
```

Details on the other Connection Security override options here:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql-blog/connection-security-improvements-in-sqlpackage-161/ba-p/3672758

Comment: Hi, the problem is related to SSMS and not sqlpackage.